# How to make a component fill a splitpane on JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

I would like to add a component on one side of a JavaFX splitpane. How to make it fill the side panel of the splitpane ? It looks like hgrow and vgrow are not available on a splitpane.

In fact, I'm trying to add a titled pane in a split pane. Here's the code :

```java
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    TitledPane titledPane1 = new TitledPane("Panel 1", new Group());
    TitledPane titledPane2 = new TitledPane("Panel 2", new Group());

    SplitPane rootPane = new SplitPane();
    rootPane.getItems().add(titledPane1);
    rootPane.getItems().add(titledPane2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
    stage.setWidth(400);
    stage.setHeight(300);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

}
```

Comment: By default, a resizable node will fill the split pane.  Please [post some code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates content which is not filling the split pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html) instead of a [Group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Group.html).

The javadoc on Group says,

> A Group will take on the collective bounds of its children and is not directly resizable.

**Edit** (as per user comments)

The problem here is not with Pane but with `TitledPane`, since TitledPane extends [`Labeled`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Labeled.html)

You can bind the titledPane's height with the splitpane's height using

> titledPane1.prefHeightProperty().bind(rootPane.heightProperty());

A working example with `TiltledPane` height bind and other with a `Pane` added to `SplitPane`

```
public class StoreNumbers extends Application {

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Pane pane1 = new Pane();
        Pane pane2 = new Pane();
        TitledPane titledPane1 = new TitledPane("Panel 1", pane1);
        TitledPane titledPane2 = new TitledPane("Panel 2", pane2);
        SplitPane rootPane = new SplitPane();
        rootPane.getItems().add(titledPane1);
        rootPane.getItems().add(pane2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootPane);
        stage.setWidth(400);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        pane1.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
        pane2.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, null, null)));
        titledPane1.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED, null, null)));
        titledPane2.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, BorderStrokeStyle.DASHED, null, null)));
        titledPane1.prefHeightProperty().bind(rootPane.heightProperty());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested with a Pane as child of the TitledPane, but it does'nt change. The TitledPane still does not fill its parent, eg the SplitPane.

Comment: It works nicely now using the pref height property binding. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
titledPane1.setMaxHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Also solves the problem in the cases I've seen.